# Caret package in Microsoft Azure ML

Tags: r, azure, load, r-caret, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to load caret library in Azure ML. This works when R version is set to be CRAN R 3.1.0, but on Microsoft R Open 3.2.2 won't work. I must use R Open version because of the other packages that I'm using in my project, which are not supported in that earlier version 3.1.0.
Therefore, the question is how to load this library on ML Azure using Microsoft R Open 3.2.2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From one of your comments above, it sounds like the version of the `caret` package you've used requires an R version >3.1.2. I recommend using an older version of the package: the `caret` binary from [this 3.1 archive](http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/) (6.0-68) worked for me. I used these statements to load the package:

```
install.packages("src/caret_6.0-68.zip", lib=".", repos= NULL, verbose=TRUE)
library("caret", lib.loc=".", verbose=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The caret package is now pre-installed on Azure ML Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/r-packages-supported-by-azure-machine-learning#bkmk_C
Regards,
Jaya

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the R library you want as a zip file and you refer that within the code. Here's a nice step by step reference from MSDN explaining the process of adding a R library for the experiment.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjguin/2014/09/24/how-to-upload-an-r-package-to-azure-machine-learning/

Comment: Actually I did that already. The problem is that the package cannot run because of R version 3.1.0 on ML Azure (it requires >3.1.2). Also I cannot  use Microsoft R Open because of usage of other packages.